# Template Argument in Template-Class Assignment Operator

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am trying to write a generic class `MyStack` to implement a Stack. I have a template variable inside my class by the typename of `Data`. I am also overloading the `= operator` to copy an existing `MyStack` object to another existing `MyStack` object. I therefore want to check if two class objects have the same type of variable before copying i.e, I don't want an object of type `float` to be copied to an object of type `int`. What would be a good way to achieve this task ?

`MyStack` Definition :

```
template<typename Data>
class MyStack
{
    Data *data;
    int pos;
    int Max;
    MyStack();

    public:

    MyStack(int);
    int push(const Data);
    int push(const Data *,const Data);
    Data pop();
    Data* pop(const int);
    int getMaxSize();
    int currSize();
    int isEmpty();
    void display();
    MyStack(const MyStack &);
    void operator=(const MyStack s);
    ~MyStack();
};
```

And here's the operator overloading part :

```
template<typename Data>
void MyStack<Data>::operator=(const MyStack s)
{
    cout<<"Copied with operator overloading"<<endl;
    delete[] data;
    data=new Data[s.Max];
    Max=s.Max;
    pos=s.pos;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.pos;i++)
            data[i]=s.data[i];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have a `MyStack` object because `MyStack` is a template, not a type. That may be the root of your confusion.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. The compiler will check it for you.

Comment: Unrelated: look up 'c++ self-assignment'.

Answer (score 1):

In the declaration

```
void operator=(const MyStack s);
```

You have a number of problems (see [overloading special members](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/)):

1. The return type should be `MyStack<Data> &`.
2. `s` should be a const reference.
3. The type to which `s` should be a const reference to, is `MyStack<Data>` as well.

Note that `MyStack` is not an actual type. It is a "type factory".

Overall, then, it should look like

```
MyStack<Data> &operator=(const MyStack<Data> &s);
```

This will incidentally solve your question - it will only take const references to `MyStack` templates instantiated to the same `Data`.

---

If you would like to support assignments from other stack types as well, you might consider something like the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Data>
class MyStack
{
...

    template<typename OtherData>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_convertible<OtherData, Data>::value,
        MyStack<Data> &>::type
        operator=(const MyStack<OtherData> &other);
};
```

This uses:

- [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) to check whether `OtherData` is convertible to `Data`
- [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to define it only for types convertibel to `Data`.

Comment: Not worth an answer so adding as a comment: the behavior described here is the default one; if the OP wants to assign stacks of *different* types, then they should define `template<typename Data, typename T> MyStack<Data>& MyStack::operator=(const MyStack<T>&)`, and implementing this might be tricky.

Comment: @AmiTavory I changed the overloading declaration as you said but can you please explain why  the code was working even with the previous declaration?

Comment: @iksemyonov I was trying to do exactly the way you were saying but how do I declare the prototype inside the class this way.

Comment: @SouravKanta See update for your question regarding other types. As to your question on why it built - some compilers (esp. Visual C++) are somewhat lax in their enforcement of language rules.

Comment: Thank you so much @AmiTavory

Comment: Cool solution, didn't think about `enable_if` and `is_convertible`. Guess I need to read the STL book well. Is there any way to avoid re-typing this long type construct in the definition of the operator?

Comment: @iksemyonov Thanks! To the best of my knowledge - no; it has to be retyped. Bummer.

Comment: I mean, a `typedef` will not work because the point is to have this long `enable_if<is_convertible>> construct right at the operator declaration to prevent the operator from being instantiated, right?

Comment: @iksemyonov If I understood you correctly, then yes - that's exactly why.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, now I'm going to read up on it in Josuttis and SO